# Mixed-level Deming regression?

Tags: mixed-model, total-least-squares

Is there an implementation of Deming regression that also handles random intercepts and slopes in the sample? We have a situation where we have compelling theoretical reason to believe that one measurement influences another but not the other way around. The data consists of multiple measurements per subject of a single variable for the first variable (brain vessel diameter) and one measurement per subject of the second variable (cognitive score).

Comment: I don't know about a frequentist ML-type way to do this, but you can probably do this as a Bayesian regression using, e.g., `brms`.